# How can i rename folder/directory in Android?

Tags: android, file, directory, mediastore, android-mediascanner

i want to rename folder or directory and move all video files from source to destination directory. i tried with `renameTo()` mothod but not received proper output. also move directory using apache common IO library as below,
`FileUtils.moveDirectory(sourceFile, destinationFile);`

but also fail to get proper output. some file goes to corrupted/ghost which can not access.

please let me know how can i get output.

thank you in advance.

Comment: If you only want to rename a folder then why are you talking about moving files?

Comment: Better show your code to begin with.

Comment: @blackapps just for find required output.

Comment: I dont understand a word. `Better show your code to begin with. `